# Show url only if value is present

Tags: php, html

Goal:

Instead of showing simple **YES** or **NO**.

If value is found in record, show **hyperlink with that value** or else show text **"No"**

How to modify below code for this purpose:

```
<?php echo $row_RecordsetContacts['propertyFile'] ? '<strong>Yes</strong></br>' : 'No</br>'; ?>
<a href="propfiles/<?php echo $row_RecordsetContacts['propertyFile']; ?>">View</a>

</td>
```

Comment: Do you means anchor tag should be show only when there is value?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$file = $row_RecordsetContacts['propertyFile']; # for readability only 

if ($file)
{
    ?><a href="propfiles/<?= $file ?>">View</a><?php
}
else
{
    ?>No<?php
}
```

I also suggest to avoid mixing `echo` and HTML markup. In 99% cases it makes the code better for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
<?php 
    $prop = $row_RecordsetContacts['propertyFile'];
    if(empty($prop)) {
        echo "No";
    } else {
        echo "<a href='propfiles/$prop'>View</a>";
    }
?>
```